# BigDecimal division breaks down when dividing by factorials

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal, integer-overflow

I'm writing a brute-force solution to a combinatorics problem that involves dividing by very large numbers. I turned to BigInteger and BigDecimal to handle these, but I've come upon an error when the factorial gets big enough that I haven't been able to pin down.

```
    int n = num;
    int k = num;
    BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal("0");
    BigDecimal factorialN = new BigDecimal(factorial(n));
    BigInteger factorialI;
    BigInteger factorialJ;
    BigInteger factorialM;
    BigInteger denominator;
    double threePowerN = pow(3, n);        

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            for (int m = 0; m < k; m++) {

                if (i + j + m == n) { 
                    factorialI = factorial(i);
                    factorialJ = factorial(j);
                    factorialM = factorial(m);
                    denominator = factorialI.multiply(factorialJ);
                    denominator = denominator.multiply(factorialM);
                    denominator = denominator.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf((int)threePowerN)));
                    BigDecimal lastTerm = new BigDecimal(denominator);
                    lastTerm = factorialN.divide(lastTerm, 100, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
                    sum = sum.add(lastTerm);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // prints
    // -0.62366051209329651, which doesn't make sense because this should 
    // be a percentage between 0 and 1. 
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1").subtract(sum));
```

Here is the `factorial` method:

```
 public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    while (n != 0) {
        result = result.multiply(new BigInteger(n + ""));
        n--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

All others cases, from n = k = num = 1 to 19, all work as expected: the printed value is between 0 and 1.
Once I reach num = 20, `sum` exceeds 1, and `sum - 1` becomes negative, which makes me think there's an overflow issue here. But can this be with BigIntegers/BigDecimals?
What could be the problem here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show us the `factorial` method?

Comment: Yup, just added. Thanks @ajb

Comment: Side note: `BigInteger.valueOf(n)` will convert an `int` or `long` to a `BigInteger`.  You don't need to convert to a `String` first, which is slower--and since you're inside a triple loop, the extra time could add up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3<sup>20</sup> is too big to fit in an `int`.  So this will fail:

```
  denominator = denominator.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf((int)threePowerN)));
```

The cast will wrap around and you will actually be multiplying by a negative number.

`BigInteger` has a `pow` function.  Instead of:

```
double threePowerN = pow(3, n);
```

try

```
BigInteger threePowerN = BigInteger.valueOf(3).pow(n);
```

and then

```
denominator = denominator.multiply(threePowerN);
```

By the way, you don't have to convert your integers to `String` in order to convert them to a `BigInteger`.  `BigInteger` doesn't have a constructor that takes an integer value, but it does have a [static `valueOf` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think the new threePowerN should be written as  
`BigInteger threePowerN = BigInteger.valueOf(3).pow(n);`  
The `pow` method acts on the object itself, it doesn't accept a second parameter.